# Ubuntu Core 18 on NUC6CAYH

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-core, intel-nuc

I’m new on ubuntu core. I read the manual to install ubuntu core 18 on NUC

But in the manual, there is no certifeid for NUC6CAYH. Does that mean ubuntu core is not compatible with NUC6CAYH? or what does it mean?

This the manual link 
https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a certain system is not certified, that doesn't mean that you can't run Ubuntu on it. You can test it by downloading a live version of Ubuntu, see if everything works as expected, then install Ubuntu Core.